# Minimum of $x^2+y^2+z^2-2xyz$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm looking for the minimum of this function for real numbers, I proved that the only possible local minimum is $0$ but I didn't find a way to prove/disprove that it's a global minimum.

Comment: Are the variables assumed to positive?

Comment: no the function is defined for all reals

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no minimum if $x=y=z=t\rightarrow +\infty$ than your expression is $3t^2-2t^3 \rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: How does this discount the existence of a _local_ minimum?

Comment: OP is looking for a global minimum as far as I can understand from the question.

Comment: @AO1992 can you tell me how you came up with the idea for the counterexample (or if you know any relevant books that help develop such strategies) ? Or is it actually a standard trick in multivariable Calculus?

Comment: @wostysums it is pretty common to study the behaviour of a multivariable function by checking it on some specific curves. Here you also have a non-homogeneous polynomial which has only one term of degree 3, so this also helps